# How to call a function when the media has ended, which is played from the javascript file

Tags: javascript, cordova, media

I'm trying to run a function when the media has ended which is played from the javascript file with the media.play() function.

Just assume please that the media is already playing, below is the code that I've written so far, but it seems not to be called like this when it ended:

```
function onEnd(media){
    if(media.ended)
    {
        document.getElementById("audioButton").src ="images/playbutton.png";
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have attached `event listener` for `ended` event. Refer example given below:

```js
function getAlert() {
  alert('Clicked!');
}
document.getElementById('music').addEventListener('ended', getAlert);
```

```html
<audio autoplay id="music" controls>
  <source src="audio/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="audio/audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```